# Насколько корректно так делать внутренние объекты в javascript

Tags: javascript

Вопрос к почтенной публике, мне нужен внутренний объект, и сейчас я делаю так:

```
function FooList () {
    this.id = 0;
    this.list = {};
}
FooList.prototype = {
    add: function () {
        var item = new this.foo(this.id++, this);

        this.list[item.id] = item;
        return item;
    },
    get: function (id) {
        return this.list[id];
    },
    foo: function (id, parent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
};
FooList.prototype.foo.prototype = {
    set: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    get: function () {
        return this.name;
    }
};

// Test
var list = new FooList;
var foo = list.add();
foo.set("name");
console.log(foo);
```

Насколько это корректно (совместимо с разными броузерами)

Comment: Что такое "внутренний объект"?